# Callback to listen to flutter push notification in iOS terminated state

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In flutter firebase messaging, is there a callback to know if a push notification is received in iOS app when it is in the terminated state?
The `onBackgroundMessage` callback works for Android background and terminated states but only background state for iOS. Is there a way to listen to firebase SDK since it handles the iOS notification (when the notification parameter is set in the payload) when the app is inactive/terminated.
Thanks.

Comment: No, when the app is terminated, it isn't running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.